# Subscribing to an Akka stream, reading files

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to read a file in Scala with Akka Streams, I want to put the result in a list. I tried the following code, and the list gets incremented with new values inside the sink, but outside I get an empty list.

```
def readStream (path : String, date : String) : List[Array[String]] = {
  var lines: List[scala.Array[String]] = List[scala.Array[String]]()

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
  val settings = ActorMaterializerSettings(system)
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(settings)

  val sink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach((x : String) => {
    val list : List[scala.Array[String]] = List(x.split("|"))
    lines = lines ++ list
    // println(lines.length)
  })

  val result: Unit = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(path + "transactions_" + date + ".data"))
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true).map(_.utf8String))
    .to(sink)
    .run()
  lines
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things: (1) pass the actor system and materializer to your method (explicitly or as implicit parameters) instead of creating them inside the method, (2) use `Sink.seq`, and (3) use `toMat` and `Keep.right` to get the materialized value of the `Sink` (`to` retains the materialized value of the `Source`):

```
val result: Future[Seq[String]] =
  FileIO.fromPath(...)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right)
    .run()
```

Alternatively, a shorthand for using `toMat` and `Keep.right` is `runWith`:

```
val result: Future[Seq[String]] =
  FileIO.fromPath(...)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 256, true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .runWith(Sink.seq)
```